# Database initiation and node js cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb

With the node cluster module, it is relatively easy to spin up child processes. For example:

```js
var cluster = require('cluster');
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var cpuNum = require('os').cpus().length;
    while (cpuNum--) cluster.fork();
} else {
    var app = require('http').http.createServer(/*[http.createServer]*/);
    //using mongo database, if the database is empty, then insert some default documents
    if (!db.find()) database.insert(/*some large documents*/)
    app.listen(3000);
}
```

The problem arises when the database is empty, the first cluster.worker will execute `db.find()` and then insert some documents. However, the second or subsequence workers will also execute `db.find()` and find nothing so will also run `db.insert()`. This results in duplication of documents.

How could this (insertion duplication) be prevented when using node cluster during database initiation? Or is this more relevant to mongodb?

Comment: Initialize your database from the master, or before you spawn the worker processes.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it, but if the cluster is initiated by a third party, such as pm2 https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/, then it won't work

Comment: If you use pm2, you can have it start a separate initialization script with `autorestart` set to `false`. Since you're dealing with multiple processes, otherwise you need some sort of external synchronization mechanism.